# How Can I Solve a Non-Linear Programming Problem In Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, finance, portfolio

I have very simple model as mentioned bellow:

[image]

Assume that:

```py
CW = [1.004455981050443, 0.9937806249035503, 0.9963341786199054, 1.000775606323324, 1.0006315883554697]  
# Suppose That these are Percent of return of each bond
```

I want to solve this optimization and identify value of **b<sub>i</sub>** .

How can I code this problem in Python?

**Update:**

Suppose that I want to solve a optimization problem in my portfolio.
My final goal is to identify weights of investment(amounts between 0 and 1) in every bond that exist in the portfolio.
My bonds in portfolio :

1. Bond 1
2. Bond 2
3. Bond 3
4. Bond 4
5. Bond 5
   so my portfolio contains 5 bonds.
   I put the model(objective function and subjective in [image: this picture]

I wrote this code for solve this Optimization like this:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import math as mt

CW = [0.9862898856860483, 0.9944441063388774, 0.9934069612349462, 0.9952892270523128, 0.9951914282293151] # Suppose That these are Percent of return of each bond

def Objective(x):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    x3 = x[2]
    x4 = x[3]
    x5 = x[4]

    fin = (- (mt.log10(CW[0]* x1))) + (- (mt.log10(CW[1]* x2))) + (- (mt.log10(CW[2]* x3))) + (- (mt.log10(CW[3]* x4))) + (- (mt.log10(CW[4]* x5)))
    return fin
    

def Equality_Constraint(x):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    x3 = x[2]
    x4 = x[3]
    x5 = x[4]
    
    return x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 - 1

bounds_x1 = (0, 1)
bounds_x2 = (0, 1)
bounds_x3 = (0, 1)
bounds_x4 = (0, 1)
bounds_x5 = (0, 1)
Bounds = [bounds_x1, bounds_x2, bounds_x3, bounds_x4, bounds_x5]

Constraint1 = {'type' : 'eq', 'fun': Equality_Constraint}
Constraint = [Constraint1]

x0 = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2] #This is an initial Value

Result = minimize(Objective, x0, method='SLSQP' , bounds=Bounds, constraints=Constraint)
print(Result)
```

**Output**

```
     fun: 3.510281934983529
     jac: array([-2.17147237, -2.17147237, -2.17147237, -2.17147237, -2.17147234])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 6
     nit: 1
    njev: 1
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2])
```

Here is the problem! cause it says I should devote 20% of my total money for bound1, 20% for bound2 and so on. but its not true! the percent of investment(Weights) should be different! cause my return of bond4 = 0.9952892270523128 that this is best return between returns of each bond that mentioned as **CW** List !
This result of solver says all weights should be 0.2 and this is optimal solution! but this doesn't seems to be correct! they should be different weights!
Now can any one help me to find out where is the problem? or how can I achieve correct weights through solve optimization problem?

Comment: Ideally you try some code out first to show that you attempted to solve the problem yourself, then people here can help you out with a specific issue you're having

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm to solve this problem or are you looking for a mathematical solution? If you are looking for a mathematical solution, you should probably post your question on math stack instead.

Comment: @RolvApneseth sure! Should i create new question? Or edition of current question would be enough?

Comment: @user14518362 actually I'm looking for a python code to solve this optimization problem !

Comment: Simplex method can be used to solve optimization problems with constraints.  Simulated annealing might be another algorithm you can try.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service. "Please write code for me" is not a valid question. Providing external resources (e.g. already written code) is also off-topic. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) might be a good read.

Comment: @xdurch0 OP didn't ask you or anyone to write code for them, so the grating, hectoring tone isn't called for. The question is off topic as it stands, but there's no need to pretend that OP has offended you or anyone.

Comment: @Shayan This is a constrained optimization problem, with a smooth objective function, and bound constraints and an equality constraint. Given the smooth objective and the equality constraint, the first thing to try is Lagrange multipliers. If that gives you a solution within the bound constraints, you've solved the problem. Otherwise, one or more variables will be one a boundary. At that point it will be more work; I think you'll have to essentially reason your way through different possibilities (in an automated way of course). Follow up to math.stackexchange.com with your own work on it.

Comment: This is a convex problem (maximizing a concave objective) so we can use a tool like CVXPY. Note that all CW(i) are approximately the same.

Comment: @duffymo Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: @xdurch0 you're right about it. but I'm on difficult situation right now... . after all, I think your right about matter. I wrote a code before. but its hard for me to explain that cause my English isn't perfect at all :(((  . but thank you for you response.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thanks for your guidance. sure I'll check it out! Thank you.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks for your guidance. logarithmic objective is kind of CONVEX Programming?

Comment: @Shayan is the objective function really sum(log(CW(i)*b(i)), i=1 to 5)? If so then you don't need to work with CW, just b, since that's sum(log(CW(i), i=1 to 5) + sum(log(b(i)), i=1 to 5), so only the second term is a function of b.

Comment: @RobertDodier it seems Convincing! Thank You! I Updated The Topic if you think you can read it I will be appreciated ! with love.

Comment: Looks like you got the code to work, that's great. You got b = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2] as expected per my previous comment. The fact that b doesn't depend on CW seems to show that your objective function isn't stated correctly. Is the log necessary? I'm thinking total return(i) = (initial*b(i))*CW(i)^n, with n = number of years of investment. Anyway you can think about the objective and try some things.

Comment: @RobertDodier Yes that's specific objective function that stated in the paper that I'm working on it. so I have to handle it :(( . Okay Thanks for your kindness and time that you devoted ! Thank you.